# How to upload Ms access database to ftp?

Tags: c#, ms-access, ftp, cpanel

I have c# program , and i'm using ms access Database with it, So how i can upload my database to my domain by the code ?
I'm using MYSQL Domain "Linux".

Comment: "by the code" what does that mean?

Comment: you start by either using a FTP program windows or otherwise or you write your own code to do that.. this is not a coding farm.. so you must show what you have tried on your own...

Comment: i'm asking if it's possible !!?

Comment: Easy as this!  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for any file:

```
private void UploadFiles()
{
    string filename = Server.MapPath("file1.txt");
    string ftpServerIP = "ftp.demo.com/";
    string ftpUserName = "dummy";
    string ftpPassword = "dummy";

    FileInfo objFile = new FileInfo(filename);
    FtpWebRequest objFTPRequest;

    // Create FtpWebRequest object 
    objFTPRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + objFile.Name));

    // Set Credintials
    objFTPRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserName, ftpPassword);

    // By default KeepAlive is true, where the control connection is 
    // not closed after a command is executed.
    objFTPRequest.KeepAlive = false;

    // Set the data transfer type.
    objFTPRequest.UseBinary = true;

    // Set content length
    objFTPRequest.ContentLength = objFile.Length;

    // Set request method
    objFTPRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

    // Set buffer size
    int intBufferLength = 16 * 1024;
    byte[] objBuffer = new byte[intBufferLength];

    // Opens a file to read
    FileStream objFileStream = objFile.OpenRead();

    try
    {
        // Get Stream of the file
        Stream objStream = objFTPRequest.GetRequestStream();

        int len = 0;

        while ((len = objFileStream.Read(objBuffer, 0, intBufferLength)) != 0)
        {
            // Write file Content 
            objStream.Write(objBuffer, 0, len);

        }

        objStream.Close();
        objFileStream.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```